# Who will win Ghost?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, game

The game of Ghost is played between two players who alternate saying a letter on each turn.  At each point, the letters so far must start some valid English word.  The loser is the player to complete a full word first.  So, for example, if the letters so far are E-A-G-L, then the only valid next letter to say is "E" and so the next player will lose.  (Even though there are longer words such as "eaglet".)

### The challenge

You are to write a program or function to determine, given the letters so far, who will win assuming two perfect players.  The input is a string representing the current state of the game, and a list of strings representing the dictionary of valid words.  The output should distinguish whether the next player to go will win or lose.

### Details

- The code must handle the case where the current state is empty.  However, you may assume no word in the dictionary is empty.
- You may assume that each input string consists only of lowercase ASCII letters, i.e. a-z.
- You may assume the current state and all words in the dictionary have at most 80 characters each.
- The dictionary is guaranteed to be nonempty (to avoid the case where there is no valid first move).
- You may assume the "current state" will be valid: there will necessarily be some word starting with the current state; also, the current state will not be a full word, nor will any prefix of the current state be a full word.
- The dictionary will be prefiltered according to the rules of which "English words" are considered to be valid for the game - so for example, for a variant in which words of three or fewer letters don't end the game yet, the dictionary will be prefiltered to include only the words of four or more letters.
- You may assume the dictionary will be presorted.

### Examples

Suppose the dictionary is:

```
abbot
eager
eagle
eaglet
earful
earring
```

Then for the following current states, the output should be as follows:

```
Current state   Result
=============   ======
                loss
a               win
eag             win
eagl            loss
ear             win
earf            win
earr            loss
```

Likewise, for the word list at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dschepler/ghost-word-list/master/wordlist.txt (produced on a Debian system using `pcregrep '^[a-z]{4,80}$' /usr/share/dict/american-english`) here is a possible session:

```
Current state   Result
=============   ======
                win
h               loss
ho              win
hoa             loss
hoar            win
hoars           loss
```

(And then the next move completes "hoarse".)

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf): Shortest program in bytes for each programming language wins.

Comment: From review queue, I don't think this challenge is unclear. If you do, please post why.

Comment: I didn't vote to close, but I think the question could use a description of output. Must output be a boolean? One of two values? One of many values partitioned in two?

Comment: I'm fine with anything from which deriving a win/loss result is trivial.  Either a truthy/falsey dichotomy (in either order), or one of two values, or something like positive vs. negative integer result, etc.

Comment: @mbomb007 I have voted as unclear.  I can't really say what is unclear specifically because I don't understand the question.  I've read it five times now and I still do not understand the task at all.

Comment: @WheatWizard Each player must choose the next letter such that the partial word is still a prefix of a word in the dictionary. When there are no longer any such choices, then the game ends with the last player to go as the loser.

Comment: @WheatWizard A possible game (and thought processes of more naive players): Alice: (I'll try to force "abacus") "A". Bob: (I'll try to force "arise".) "R". Alice: (I'll try to force "aria") "I". Bob: (Playing right into my hands) "S". Alice: (Shoot, I can only think of "arise", "arisen", "arises" now.) "E, you win."

Comment: Test cases that allow more branching choices would be good.

Comment: you have a case where "ear" should win, but how? it matches two words in that dictionary: "earful","earring". And then the quickest way to a word is "earful". But no mater how it is played, with these perfect players, the opposition will. The game would play out as the following: `p1: ear, p2: earf, p1: earfu, p2: earful`.

Comment: @Dennis.Verweij With `ear` as given prefix, I would chose `R`, leaving only `earring` as possible match. Opposite must pick `I`, I pick `N`, opposite must pick `G` and loses.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, 54 bytes

```
l=>g=w=>!(w+0)||l.some(t=>t==w||!g(t.match(`^${w}.`)))
```

call it like this: f(wordlist_as_array)(current_word_as_string), it return true for win, false for lose.

quite bad performance T_T , only work with the small test case.

```js
f=
l=>g=w=>!(w+0)||l.some(t=>t==w||!g(t.match(`^${w}.`)))
```

```html
<p><label>Word List:<br/><textarea id="wl"></textarea></label></p>
<p><label>Current:<input type="text" id="c" /></label></p>
<p><button onclick="out.textContent = f(wl.value.split('\n'))(c.value)">Check</button></p>
<p>Result: <output id="out"></output></p>
```

Comment: Wow, that's an ingenious null-check!

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>135</strike> <strike>129</strike> 84 bytes

<sup>-4 bytes thanks to [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder)!</sup>

<sup>-42 bytes thanks to [Daniel Schepler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/73487/daniel-schepler)!</sup>

```python
g=lambda s,l:(s in l)or-min(g(w,l)for w in{w[:len(s)+1]for w in l if w[:len(s)]==s})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7BasMwDIbvfgohCNgsKYTdDNmLhBwcansG1Q6WSxilz545bTe2XCR9v6RfWr7KZ4rv2@YHMpf5bIBb0pIhRCCVcncJUXq5tqRcyrBW/baOmmyUrN766UcEguDgtzMNA9/VdrYOiuUiq6nSSw6xSGwYug9oGJsqw63XuIaILXS1osSM99E/FialBMEAiCjMPKcirPE275HsM@5SdlfaU3X3os6eeKFQKETLUo29nsTjBawnSL1q8xeq0wHpP@cDugM/@9s3)

A `1` indicates the current player will win, whereas a `-1` indicates they will lose.

Comment: [133 bytes](https://tio.run/##bY3LasNADEX3/ophoDBK4xKnO6fzJWYWDplxBaps5rEoIfl1V05CC6k3ehzdqzt958@R3@f55IMaTNoStGzJs0lwKLZDFcaoUCErUhiutUkynzd0qc94gY3BrmVnbQJ3iD6XKDoxF/jY93y6mtvS7RzUDC97edXUX8hmuPleGyd5vwEFZlJWaa2r/ngcc@X7wcelkr/XBcVQaGkReahE@5YmwkzIPhnomtZVk5yyRGi9VQTwt/fPQJ6uIPrP4goKK@yhm38A)

Comment: Not sure, but [131 bytes](https://tio.run/##bY1NasNADIX3PoUYKIzSuMTtzmFOYmbhkBlXoMpmfhYlxFd3x2lIofFGevr09DR9p89RPpbl7DwMOu4ZWzHsREc8ZtMR@DEAAQkwkJ9rHYu@7PhaX@iKO01dK9aYiPYYXMpB5vU4Yy/nWd9kd7BYC768l6Cm/iLRw@3qtbHl2yM@48JgQClV9afTmCrXDy6sld1vXVHwmdcWSIaqeN/ixJSYxEWNXdPaaiqrVF4otQdG/Jv7/6CEbiB@ZmED@Q129y0/)?

Comment: On the full 61135-word dictionary I posted at github and empty state I haven't been able to run it to completion (it's been running several minutes already).  I don't know the custom here for whether you need to be able to run all the test cases I posted in a reasonable time.  (On the sandbox post, I did initially have a requirement that the code not be "horribly inefficient" but commenters suggested either dropping that or specifying an asymptotic running time - and I was afraid saying "linear in the size of the input" would be too restrictive.)

Comment: [Here](https://tio.run/##XY7RasMwDEXf/RVCELBZMwh7y8h@JOQhpXZm0ORguYRR@u2p0myw5UW650pcaf4un4nf1vXiA0xWTuRa7sizFfeefblmVRAZyKVcf0W2k110KaQMi/q3pW/5pRl@GQhigM0cuk7u7plbvJQ9es6Ri8VKoP6ASrBSG25Ni0tkPEGtipII3vv9l8E5Q9ABIprxfE7F@HHyeavk97pZOVxpa5o@Gd19lZliocherOubdjDPF1BPkPvR41/QpAPSf84HDAfe5@sD) is an experiment with using an intermediate set to eliminate the duplicate recursive calls.  With this, it's at least able to process the full dictionary in a few minutes.  (I was also experimenting with another simplification, so the net result is a decrease to 87 bytes.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler Nice! I was working on a similar way to reduce recursive calls, but your method is a lot more concise! It also allows me to reduce this to a `lambda`.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>192 154 100</s> 98 bytes

```php
function t($w,$d){foreach(preg_grep("#^$w#",$d)as$p)if($p==$w||!t($w.$p[strlen($w)],$d))return 1;}
```

function returns `1` for win, `NULL` for loss.
Call with `t(string $word,array $dictionary)`
or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d2313c8cd84141d5fffd235dde012e7888f28e42).

**breakdown**

```php
function t($w,$d)
{
    // loop through matching words
    foreach(preg_grep("#^$w#",$d)as$p)if(
        $p==$w                      // if word is in dictionary (previous player lost)
        ||                          // or
        !t($w.$p[strlen($w)],$d)    // backtracking is falsy (next player loses)
    )
        return 1;                   // then win
    // implicit return NULL
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## C++, 243 bytes (noncompetitive)

FYI, here's the golfed version of my reference implementation (marked as noncompetitive since it's my own challenge).  It expects the word list in the `w` parameter to be a null-terminated array (of null-terminated strings).  It returns `1` if the next player will lose, or `0` if the next player will win.

```
#define r return
int g(char*s,char**w){struct N{int d=0;N*c[128]{};int l(){if(d)r 0;for(N*p:c)if(p&&p->l())r 0;r 1;}void a(char*s){*s?(c[*s]?:c[*s]=new N)->a(s+1),0:d=1;}N*f(char*s){r*s?c[*s]->f(s+1):this;}}d;for(;*w;d.a(*w++));r d.f(s)->l();}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##fVPtjqIwFP3PUzQzidMiEt1fG1HmDXwBx5DaFmwGCtsWu7OEZ2fbgoqZ7Dbh9nrv6bmfkqZZFYQMwytlORcMSCCZbqUIuNCggOSCZagif4UGdUrLlmhw6Jyb7tfJISTHzY@fp65PnKmEqOM5pEiCdZLXEh7CZkuQNTWLRbNKrd@7JNgk/bXmFOApBupC9Q7JMVSn962/9oIZcECrFEO13KBovaV7@@oQ5vcnVrx77CrNPWirL1wlfU998CQ0CY0xDM1yiZANSmMLQz6NpB9euSBlSxnY8doWxnCVBg@btXBRzC1XRnQt5xbyHVSxqpZfcwsui1pyfXli55pJ7NnYb6sKMOs3UBEYOw4MSgI/igpzAZ2CZUEmt9OvxxMCXQDsUZput2NCwNDkYRvz3nm9FfxXy7JGy53jOJ7S1ILViDYXXjIAPbBgurQLMf4gXEQWhm6h3MGtroEB@zFGhT9ZNpLfiKGhseJ/GERgCTYoub@8JUqaL2hiGwgixx6TzBrtgjyQNrO4adUlO2PyOaZS1VcGzQ3UB9/K9K1JQStqIxjN7sV5jJZYKLsaFXTUZ1bYrvrgKmaCOtXDXLiMC8WknQ2cUaHontvsHE@Q1EJp8I8WL@wcQTf9s8BUcgL6qYgZ/6xa0Zal5XALcE/fZp4xTC7QTX65ifwGLMeVOC5O0/qY@ZjG@dWtBrudHZcVbx/67dFingNYQBM9ZUGxxnYQ6KnYJ6aXslbqQ7w8iFip2H/whos7vL8VNXVknQR9MODzudYBwwWTTpZslM4k87Z0l9vtYcCDdbivtEK6L3dC/gU)

Expanded and commented version:

```
int g(char* s, char** w) {
    /// Node of the prefix tree
    struct N {
        int d = 0;  ///< 1 if the node represents a word in the dictionary
        N* c[128] {};  ///< child nodes, indexed by integer value of character

        // Optional, if you want to eliminate the memory leak from the
        // golfed version.  (Though actually in practice, I would make
        // "c" into std::array<std::unique_ptr<N>, 128> so the default
        // destructor would be sufficient.)
        // ~N() { for (N* p : c) delete p; }

        /// \retval 1 if the next player going from this node will lose
        /// \retval 0 if they will win
        int l() {
            if (d)
                return 0;  // last player lost, so the player who would
                           // have gone next wins
            for (N* p : c)
                if (p && p->l())
                    return 0;  // found a letter to play which forces the
                               // other player to lose, so we win
            return 1;  // didn't find any such letter, we lose
        }

        /// Add word \p s under this node
        void a(char* s) {
            *s ?
                (c[*s] ?: c[*s] = new N) // use existing child node or create new one
                ->a(s+1), 0  // the ,0 just makes the branches of
                             // the ternary compatible
            :
                d = 1;
        }

        /// Find node corresponding to \p s
        N* f(char* s) {
            return *s ?
                c[*s]->f(s+1)
            :
                this;
        }
    } d;  // d is root node of the prefix tree

    // Construct prefix tree
    for (; *w; d.a(*w++))
        ;

    // Find node for input, then run the "loser" method
    return d.f(s)->l();
}
```