# Return a word with a prescribed sum of letters

Tags: code-golf, natural-language

Identify each letter of the English alphabet with the number denoting its position in the alphabet, that is,

`a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, ..., z = 26`

(no distinction between lower and upper case letters is made). Every other character is identified with `0`.

The "sum" of a word is the sum of its characters, for example: the sum of `e-mail` is `40 = 5 + 0 + 13 + 1 + 9 + 12`, since `e = 5, - = 0, m = 13, a = 1, i = 9, l = 12`.

**The Challenge**

Write a program or a function that takes as input an integer `n` in the range 10-100 and returns a word of the English language whose sum is equal to `n`

This is codegolf, [standard loopholes are forbidden](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default).

**ADDENDUM:**

- For a list of English words, see: https://github.com/dwyl/english-words
- Reading a remote list of words is forbidden.

Comment: Welcome to code golf! This appears to almost be a good challenge, you just have one significant problem: you haven't defined the English language. I would personally recommend saying the submissions are allowed to take a lexicon of English words as a free argument. For the future, please consider using our [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/31625) to work through such problems before posting.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I don't understand what your suggestion of "taking a lexicon of English words as a free argument" means.

Comment: Essentially, you need to somehow define what is a valid English word. @FryAmTheEggman suggested adding a list of possible English words as an input.

Comment: I've been trying to find a good example of another challenge that does this, the best I have found so far is [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/140067/31625), though I am certain there are others.

Comment: I see. But what is a valid English word is something that is decided by the entirely community of English speakers. Therefore, I think that a better solution would be that each answers post the list of "n - word" pairs of its solution, and people upvote or downvote if they think the words are valid or not.

Comment: Hmm, this can be a very cool Kolmogorov-complexity problem then. The requirement can be: with no input, output the English words for n from 1 to 100 or something.

Comment: I'm afraid that just isn't how this site works. Solutions must be verifiable objectively. And besides, it isn't unreasonable to require that the program adapt to what the user decides is valid English.

Comment: @Nik Challenges on this site are required to be objective, with posters being able to validate and score their solutions as they post. We've found that asking voters to vote based on a certain judgment is ineffective and does not make for good quality control.

Comment: If we cannot assume the knowledge of English, we can probably assume xnor has just said "I approve of this question. Have you considered also allowing Spanish?".

Comment: As an alternative to making the dictionary be an input, I think a good way to go is to specify your own dictionary by linking to a downloadable file (that code is not allowed to access) in the question. Then it becomes a compression-style challenge about finding a good set of words to use for each length.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman and xnor: Would adding a link to any English dictionary make the challenge objectively verifiable?

Comment: I think so, but I think it's also important for the word list to be something that can be downloaded and not just queried online.

Comment: The word list looks good. Could you please also link to the file directly? (Edit: Saw you already answered my question about capitals.)

Comment: Would it be reasonable to drop the 'word' idea/requirement and just say that any ascii alphabetic string input should return the sum?

Comment: @ouflak No, that's the funny part. Otherwise, "aaa...a" (n times a) would do it.

Comment: Due to some confusion, I think you should clearly edit in that only those words in the file count as English words. Thank you for making the suggested changes, so far.

Comment: I looked at the words.txt file at the github link you gave (you should specify that that's the file you meant, if it is).  That word list looks good -- it appears to include most grammatical forms (plurals, participles, etc.).  I'd happy if you replaced "returns a word in the English language" with "a word in https://github.com/dwyl/english-words/words.txt" (but of course your code can't download that file!).  This is a good challenge!

Comment: I should add that I don't think we should be able to pass the entire word list as an argument for free.  That would make it much less interesting.  (If you want to include the word list in your code, you should have to count all the bytes in it!)

Comment: I think the file you really want us to use is `words_alpha.txt` rather than `words.txt`, right? (cc @MitchellSpector)

Comment: @Arnauld  You could be right (I didn't compare them), but my other comments stand.  (And this confirms that OP should specify the specific file used as a reference for what's an English word.)

Comment: The most important question is whether your program can read from a file for free, or if you have to count the bytes in any external file in your byte count.  Some people seem to be assuming that you can use an external file for free, but that seems to me to go against both the spirit of the challenge and general codegolf scoring rules.

Comment: @MitchellSpector From my understanding you aren't allowed to read a file at all. You need to store the words you want to output (compressed) inside your program. This challenge is mostly about choosing the shortest 90 words to compress, then it is about actually returning them based on the input.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen That's what I thought also, but some of the answers seem to have assumed otherwise, so I thought it was worth spelling out.

Comment: I think you should just tell us which is the official word list to use for this challenge, direct link. So we all can use the same accepted words. Whether that list is a good or bad list of the English language is beyond the point here.

Comment: Here's a program that takes the smallest words 10-100 from the wordlist. Runs in about a second on words.txt: https://tio.run/##ZVHRboMgFH3nK@66pEJal/ZVrD@yNQ1BakkUDGKXpfXbHeBW6MbL5R7PuZx75H2fN5zP86tUvB1rAaXUgzWCdRWKmEOkalKEc/vVixTpWF8hJFUrlQCpLHxqU5@4HpXFXKvBwmDrolhGwdpVgm4I3PFkc5toaM7aYDZaDRwKCCT4OQY2B8AccsAZy1zZEwJryLEcWNtfGOakqvY7sswxwo5GgaFo8q4sdEwqfNWy/n02teNN04i6XUqn2aacCoaOte3JrzVQ9DBLoRHW63Egc6m2YRyhsHi/PTZYYvBmQixwSDNaNH@4T5Hx0ThJ4uI9KI9RJM/4xbHeWqEae8EE7nd46qtg7dHHcMPq/ya752IyU9zZryDdx/2Oulr6i79tNnHgEoYeLZSl55SwKmDla/qMPHok@1CZ@0/z/A0

Comment: Please don't be discouraged by the few downvotes or the comment flood. Despite the initial confusion about the rules, I think that's a pretty cool first challenge. The task is now quite clear but it would be better to link to the exact file we're supposed to use rather than the GitHub repository.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>262</s> 235 bytes

```python
lambda x:f'JKLmGoPlheAhVegytMtosOdtthfvtWypvttgYsRWspytps    e  eegli ra eehnkPooeoroyyauiuruotoituooup    b   aggd  p ai    mnrwiwpnwsnyotrosturwutr{"":8}d{"":14}gnlz   nht ntkpstmsltty'[(k:=x-10)//46*23+k%23::46].strip()+k//23%2*'er'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FU5La8MwGLvvV5hCSdJ2y5NSDD3sNNiDlR1WxraDSxzHJPFn7M9NvNHfnrpCQkLoIO2xBVXutJmb/c/cs@FUMzLRJnp@eR2e4NC3/LH95MLjG4J9rxHb5oxHr8@I4st@HK32qC0J4IFc9JIYFkKrugMABwPeMyedcYAg0QE4fVufgpgQNSGaMHlrBmVGOWo1WuUBDVh0ZnRo/hcLurvUN8uri1D9XxirFonCTlscbI/oo@@4o/vpPs@SNK22q6Jcd8uipLTa/j5YNFLHybpL06JcFquIm2huwJCJSBXuKsHjPNuQPMsTehceGakwnjakiackma8)

Uses words from the list that appear with and without a trailing `er`, cutting the number of required words almost in half.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>217</s>  205 bytes

An idea similar to the one [used by ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/201298/58563).

Most words are used twice: once with the `-ty` suffix (which is worth \$45\$ points) and once without it.

```javascript
n=>"JK"[n-10]||["Hwy",,"Yor",,"Yot"][n-56]||"KaMMaOPQCanSTAtMiAmiCatDuBawBetGilBolPieBitBooCooEmpToFooBunCotDotKitBoxBusButCutJotJaunGusGutYesUmpJutSixMusUnsNut".match(/.[a-z]*/g)[(n-12)%45]+(n>55?'ty':'')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVDLbtswELz7KxYCCpKVzThpHDQPObDkR2PHTQonh0DQgZBpR4HNFchlnVe/3aXcS4EFdjAz2Bnsi/qtXGmrmjoGl3q/SvYm6UfTWZSbznG3@PzMox@7t6jdjp7Q/lsUFUHsnQUxmqn5XN3d/8qUWTwMaF4NtlWmaOhTtUs1TapNipv7SqcVpYgZ4mhbP@AYMfUmQxoizRrlNfUu9ZR5miJNlTcT7yaenrR73NZTT4vqde7do3E/PUVyq6h85kcyV5334uvRWuQ8lD0RX057RcxNv9e7ZvTGLhgTe1ei1ZCAg6QPuZTSFdLqpS8153UbStHwNcRQSsJb3GmbKae5kOWzsll4yYC4gA6cn7WhK1qtFVpuwr3j7iUYuGpAg@JYwEcLoETjcKPlBtd8xY2QtVqOzJJ/FyHi0OVAixC2IFuZNT9YFqQs8W@NiUGYGPh/ZkiSkHUN7G7G4ALYeHBzOxoyIVp/9n8B)

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org),  <s>325 ... 240</s>  235 bytes

Words of \$3\$ to \$5\$ letters ending in either `"d"` or `"y"`, with the penultimate letter deduced from the other ones.

```javascript
n=>(w="EAGCABCABACBCCHFABAAAAdBADFaFGAAAKBCASCDBFEYLGNHHArOPSPPTOYRSDoCoDoCuFoEyYaLoYoNoSpSiPoOoRoToAttCurIzAtyButCurDizSuDruExpYesMurFurYumMusMizBuz".match(/.[a-z]*/g)[n-10])+(B=Buffer)([B(w+(c=n>27?'y':'d')).map(c=>n+=96-c)&&n+64])+c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZBLb@MgFIX3@RVXXdQwrmnaGWX6GFLhV1I1aaK6GyvKAmGcetSChaFpPJrfnsFZDbpInw7n3gP85p@8E6ZpbaR0JY81PSo6RXt6lrFZwmJfLImTZJ578KuKWZrzfObxyR8WSRrnWbmYPc/nzKzWxXr9uipfilQn2m@X6@xQ8oUu9bMu2qJZ65V@0a@aWZs489gze4jdgGnTFy41LvtqS9ktncmdKd3H0nXLpo9df0Y@uBVv6JJseNRvv13u8EZFV@MtDlFMY1fX0mC0idE@RIKq6fXPh@AQ3AVVgLFvbb04VSG9nUQCn5@rcPLDd4pjJ7SRQKEDOoUNIaTbEiMrJyRC7QUIPOgthCCI1Qu9lybhnUSYiDduEv9hzCIMEdxOLmCMR6NaG6T8vKvxPSj4NcBAYYjhzwhAaNXpd0ne9Q7VSGHS8ipTFbrBPuJ0l5OMfVhhTaN26GQpLDcWfR9MAfgKAf1nBkp91gMEq6cA7iDI2eMiS/27R3@P/wA)

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>187</s> <s>51</s> 48 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
žĆ•o‹§d∍(Ì•3в¾7:65Å1«.¥žy+èãJε„'ÿ.V}ʒAsSk>OQ}Réθ
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##AVcAqP9vc2FiaWX//8W@xIbigKJv4oC5wqdk4oiNKMOM4oCiM9Cywr43OjY1w4UxwqsuwqXFvnkrw6jDo0rOteKAnifDvy5WfcqSQXNTaz5PUX1Sw6nOuP//NTk) (Pretty slow unfortunately, so no test suite, but [here is a list of all the words used](https://pastebin.com/7aAgCyMp).)

**Explanation:**

```python
  •o‹§d∍(Ì•           # Push compressed integer 13897672729830113
    3в                # Convert it to base-3 as list: [2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,0,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2]
      ¾7:             # Replace the 0 with a 7
         65Å1         # Push a list of 65 1s
             «        # And append it to the list
              .¥      # Undelta the list (with leading 0): [0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,21,22,...]
                žy+   # Add 128 to each: [128,130,131,...]
žĆ                 è  # Index each into the 05AB1E codepage builtin
ã                     # Get the cartesian product with itself, to create all possible pairs
 J                    # Join each pair together
  ε     }             # Map over each pair:
   „'ÿ               '#  Push string "'ÿ", where the `ÿ` is automatically filled with the current pair we're mapping over
      .V              #  And eval it as 05AB1E code, pushing the dictionary word
ʒ       }             # Filter the list of words by:
 A                    #  Push the alphabet
  s                   #  Swap to take the current word we're filtering over
   S                  #  Convert it to a list of characters
    k                 #  Get the index of each letter inside the alphabet
     >                #  Increase it by 1 to make the 0-based indices 1-based
      O               #  Sum them all together
       Q              #  And check if it's equal to the (implicit) input-integer
R                     # Then reverse the list of remaining words (work-around for input n=11,
                      # which otherwise would result in "fda", which is not in OP's list)
 é                    # Then (stable) sort all words based on length, from shortest to longest
  θ                   # And only leave the last one
                      # (after which it is output implicitly as result)
```

Unfortunately, not all words that can be found in [the 05AB1E word list](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/lib/reading/dictionary/words.ex) can be found in the provided list as well.

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (sections *How to use the dictionary?*, *How to compress large integers?*, and *How to compress integer lists?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210), to understand how the dictionary words and compressed integer list works.

---

**Original 187 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) answer:**

```
“„é…ªƒ…°»ØÎ‰éãŠêˆÜŠ°í©ÓŽÄÍÝ‚†–ìŠÑÞã™Ä‡ÉˆÁ³²áäÁÑÆ©…¥Ê†…íÆ±Ñœ›Ç²èœÊ‚ì€€Šµ€„±½†íª¯ÅÝ‚îäÔÈÃÞºì¤ƒ‚ž¨€º¢êˆ¨ïëïÆÐ¼ˆÌ²Ï……ƒÔ…ÙÒ„±ÞŒÂä†ÔÚ´´½é‚¤»œË´¥º™Žâ¤Ñ¸‚É„¾ÈÕˆî†Û‚äŠÁ‹‚Œæ‹Ì†ÏƒÓ‡È…Ï‰Éƒà‚ë„¶™£“#sè
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##HZFNUsJAEIUP4xlceBytcuHKBRcYEBEURRKs0oipkAQq/IN/JUFY9Kth4y3mIvF1amYqqe5@8728XFZOzy7Oi8KZvjMhxs6MZHLw9LGSLZ7x4MwKYyQ2wuSvgb6NZIW5jOHbHeq4x5szgTORMz5mHOoiROLqMerODNCipCof8o4BUlTZbUjJGOK2FI0wZ2mNrvWdyXHDycz62gwwczXdJH7pmwllLTuqiJ/IEtclGgte3EMTVwglx0xSdR/YvWQUSS6x@pYMS0x5GniUX5pqE9QhnvvgoadGXuCVDITWQw2pknoI5JNrp8kEksqW5u5YGErOj2QEsaToyo86aal8TytPBCxU/qrllKlUndmoKw8kbtDWZodgX0NqKr2jObdYilQz1au@SZCEf@aogqwojk/@AQ) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##HZHNTsJQEIVfxeDWd@AlfAFNXLhyQWLC7oJYQVGkxUQrNgUKKf/gX6AIizm5bFz5CvMidaa596bNzJz7nZ5eFE5Oz8/S47@yXV0W87kDdtyDXL6YsmmzCTBkM6DR3tXHgjZ4xgObBYbo2RCjXwdtG9ICUxrCs1tUcI83Nj6bkI2HiQw1EaDHlS4qbDqoiaREH/SODiKUpOtQxujjNhMNMJXSEk3rsUlwI5Ox9bTpY8Jl3UL80jcT0JK2ohL8iOa4ztCYycUtVHGFgBJMKFL3vt1RLCJKqKu@KcYcYzkOHulHTNUF1BC87L2Llhp5gZsxEFgXZURKasGnT1lbTcaniDZi7k4KfUrkIyWCLkVo0kqd1FS@EytPApip/FXLkaRSYrNWVy6EuEZdmw0BexpSVekNzbkmpVA1Y73qWwjUkz9zWECcHqX/).

I've chosen random words which are both in the English dictionary provided, as well as in [05AB1E word list](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/lib/reading/dictionary/words.ex).

**Explanation:**

```python
“...“     # Dictionary string containing all words, space-separated
     #    # Split it on spaces
      s   # Swap to get the (implicit) input
       è  # And used it to index into the list (0-based and with wrap-around,
          # so 91-100 wrap around to the first few words)
          # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[Here is just the dictionary string part of the program.](https://tio.run/##HZFLTsNAEETPChILViy4wCSYEEPAxA4SmGA5thPl/@En4pAsujTZcIu5iKm2Zka2urvmlcsXlyen52dV5UzfmQQTZ0YyPYb6WMsOz3hwZo0Jcpti@tdC36ayxkImiOweHu7x5kzsTOpMhDmHukiQOy@D58wAPiUN@ZB3DFCgwW5LasYQt7VohAVLG3Rt5EyJG06ObaTNGHPX1E3il76ZRDayp4r4qaxwXaOx5MU9tHGFRErMpVD3sT3ImCIpJVPfMsYKM54WHuWXpjoEBcRzH0P01MgLwpqBxIZoolBSD7F8cu01mVgK2dHcHQtDKfmRjCCTAl35USe@yg@08kTAUuWvWi6YSsOZrboKQeIWHW0GBEcaUlvpgebss5SqZqZXfZMgOf9MVf0D)

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to use the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210), to understand how the dictionary string works.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 361 bytes

```perl
say''.(memGunzip(decode_base64('H4sIAINkcl4CAx2PC3LDIBBDL/Qu5Q+JneJAgbVZTl/RGWA0WkloQ2BdDs6Niy+JPRIi50llqZyRRTcUQsWJX1Znc943wXnpDFLBLlIjdqLza9RGckaiF4pTneYyVvpD76w2CGKOp/FNDx+7eYs77sk5P24KdbLmaVSytNmcYp3Uhb1Tpa/S7pPY0nAF32x2T9BVTv6P6ek+pilyuWrlohYvG4M8jcdE1YsG1oZa5kftpuaaE7dmCpBvs6Lk/Rz66LFh7CrjLG7qGsOkc2pa9GVFOFq3mVHV/Po3aefhfyb5uBZsAQAA'))=~/\w+/g)[-10+pop]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VdHLbqpAAIDhx1FDWu5QTVxwEYodFSjFQts0A4wVGZjRERQX59EPbbo4yVn9i3/5UXTC6jAw2I9G9@Ma1W7b3Eo6LlBOCvSZQYY0ZTx6VJhneOsqx4plXCXfkoHtmaYN@KBVA27ZoKXxlcVphPnQ3RrCtsIkkMzCZtq67LmlH3qlKmB8TPswjPKXgG2Xr2La5FNFvrw21HaACbB3KI7gBqehm1ewdBQaNSjp447aunaRLPdpQ3lnbV85HSVM11ml@pLyVGSghvFzf17XeULll30mRhTyzzr1E6ExHFm6StHUjKNO8zVUcbTEfbs9YbJPOldZPRzyYiEmzBVJCtVqd6YthAu9qC1qdkwDFR/eNA04e906HYCrH122qXKJwqkbOxvnKNfxY8z7RIZot9/1mdqaKTMCwxhNJvM//PuF478mb3eiwFFCP4ZhEAXhL6HnkjRsuFt16r0o/NQiNT0hxmazFJfZ/J/Ez1p5q8VsZv5SzP@D@QY)

Ungolfed program.pl:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use v5.10;
use MIME::Base64 'decode_base64';
use Compress::Zlib 'memGunzip';

# base64-encoded gzip'ed string of 91 words:
my $data=<<'';
H4sIAINkcl4CAx2PC3LDIBBDL/Qu5Q+JneJAgbVZTl/RGWA0WkloQ2BdDs6Niy+JPRIi50
llqZyRRTcUQsWJX1Znc943wXnpDFLBLlIjdqLza9RGckaiF4pTneYyVvpD76w2CGKOp/FN
Dx+7eYs77sk5P24KdbLmaVSytNmcYp3Uhb1Tpa/S7pPY0nAF32x2T9BVTv6P6ek+pilyuW
rlohYvG4M8jcdE1YsG1oZa5kftpuaaE7dmCpBvs6Lk/Rz66LFh7CrjLG7qGsOkc2pa9GVF
OFq3mVHV/Po3aefhfyb5uBZsAQAA

say ''.(memGunzip(decode_base64($data))=~/\w+/g)[-10+pop]
```

Run:

```perl
for n in {10..100};do echo -n "n=$n "; perl program.pl $n; done
.
.
.
n=95 potsy
n=96 furzy
n=97 luxus
n=98 musty
n=99 mizzy
n=100 buzzy
```

Improvement: I could have search for words in `words.txt` that gave shorter gzip'ed `$data`. Probably shortest AND most similar word from one `n` to the next.

Comment: You can shave off some bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VdFNb6JAAIDhv9JDk7Yhlm9YTDzwIVPsqEApFnY3ZoCxIgOMjqB42J@@bLOHTfb0Ht7jQ/GJqON4v509Pta4Bl1zK@ldgfO2wNsMMawpdw8vCvNMb1XlRLHNq@TbMnQ8y3IgH3RqwC0avDA/sziNCB@CjSlsKtIGklU4TFuVA7fwQ69UBUKO6RCGUf4esM3iQ0yb3FDky0dDHRdakHiH4ghvyAhBXqHSVWjU4GSIe@ro2kWyweua8u7KuXI6Tpius0r1JeW1yGCN4rfhvKrzhMrv@0yMKOLfdOonQmO6snSVIsOKo17zNVxxtCRDtzmRdp/0QFl@O@TFXEwYENsUqdXuTDuE5npR29TqmQYrPrxpGnT3un06QKAfAVtXuUSRAWJ37R7lOn6Jeb@VEd7td0OmdlbKzMA0H55mv/gfF47/fPp@v52Iws9xNIzfLT2XbcPGybJXn0Xhq3Zb0xNmbDpNSZnN/iF8raW3nE@n1l@F2X8m44T@AQ "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 574 bytes

```c
char*s[]={"ee","afd","ic","m","n","o","dl","el","ii","s","as","il","3rd","er","es","y","ln","by","cy","gv","ey","fy","fz","or","um","ot","lx","yl","ym","yn","yo","zo","xr","yr","ys","ty","bys","xw","xx","buz","ety","hwt","now","yew","guz","hvy","hwy","kyu","yor","yum","yot","you","puy","yow","yox","yoy","suz","swy","doxy","cozy","xxv","cuvy","xxx","eyry","yawy","xyz","yoky","youp","prys","fuzz","yoyo","huzz","yows","yowt","typw","burys","muzz","yutu","xyst","curvy","dizzy","wuzu","druxy","ayuyu","yesty","potsy","furzy","yummy","yours","yourt","buzzy"};f(n){n=s[n-10];}
```

Wordlist generated using [my program](https://tio.run/##ZVHRboMgFH3nK@66pEJal/ZVrD@yNQ1BakkUDGKXpfXbHeBW6MbL5R7PuZx75H2fN5zP86tUvB1rAaXUgzWCdRWKmEOkalKEc/vVixTpWF8hJFUrlQCpLHxqU5@4HpXFXKvBwmDrolhGwdpVgm4I3PFkc5toaM7aYDZaDRwKCCT4OQY2B8AccsAZy1zZEwJryLEcWNtfGOakqvY7sswxwo5GgaFo8q4sdEwqfNWy/n02teNN04i6XUqn2aacCoaOte3JrzVQ9DBLoRHW63Egc6m2YRyhsHi/PTZYYvBmQixwSDNaNH@4T5Hx0ThJ4uI9KI9RJM/4xbHeWqEae8EE7nd46qtg7dHHcMPq/ya752IyU9zZryDdx/2Oulr6i79tNnHgEoYeLZSl55SwKmDla/qMPHok@1CZ@0/z/A0) run as `program < words.txt`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NVHLbsIwELzzFVYkpKSABOqtKV9COYQ8iEUTR34kcRDfnnrG1JLH653d2V27PNzLcl3LttAf5nI9P5O6TvZJ0VQBZRmgC7sPW4Vd/QaoAVIGMIgESLg@NXJqDYDTh/2LzBusEnAfQcJqCAt0keBQRVlkzEiFnofPQ8Cj9gKYEewJKGE95WHOEwDJNwfZmlw7QbNXIH0NvJNtx8gCH96xBlXZiGcnXsE/OE@bCorNKXgMdQwVKjVzRLV4NoEpSzfGy8yRNVUKhs9@ocwjKrsBZTSnaNwSOY7c/t8mEw/LmYeJU8aM7h3jrKO0sSyuWb2SC1ua3AK20o6NFt7FmWvDVxqUNfwPpxkeXqF796bN@7TxZQP/ypu0z5792Vz6w@l4zV@r7K3oCtmno5JVtnluRFiN0ikIKc7idMzD@Q0D1m6XMQRr0CGoSZNt9SW25if8t5B70aQyy/LNa/0D)

Comment: I think you can ditch the `char` at the beginning.